# Visual Studio Tab change color?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, colors, tabs

Can I change back/fore color of tabs in Visual Studio 2008?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a tool for this?

Comment: No. Now I use Eclipse (android) :)

Comment: Very interested in changing the inactive tab color on Dark theme. I can never find it!

Answer (score 8):

Now it can be done by Visual studio Productivity Power Tools Extension.

The extension can be installed through Tools => Extensions and Updates.

After installation restart Visual Studio and go to:

Options => Productivity Power Tolls => Custom Document Well, then you can choose Color tabs by project or by regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

this visual studio 2010 addin will allow the tabs to be coloured by a specific project type- so everything in 1 project has the same colour.

read more about it and download it http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Comment: I have VS2008 and not understand, how install vsix-file

Comment: sorry i have retagged the original question to include vs2008

Answer (score 1):

You can change color and shape of tabs in VS 2008/2010 with [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com) add-in (developed by me).

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking free add-in